# cakephp 3.8.13 add admad/cakephp-jwt-auth

Tags: authentication, jwt, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.8

**This question is asked many times in the stack overflow but I tried every accepted solution**.

I'm new to cake PHP and I was assigned to add JWT in our application. Previously the team used the default cake sessions. In order to integrate, I used `admad/cakephp-jwt-auth`. So In the AppController

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Recurring');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                'storage' => 'Memory',
                'authenticate' => [
                    'Form' => [
                        'fields' => [
                            'username' => 'user_name',
                            'password' => 'password',
                        ],
                        'contain' => ['Roles']
                    ],
                    'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                        'parameter' => 'token',
                        'userModel' => 'CbEmployees',
                        'fields' => [
                            'username' => 'id'
                        ],
                        'queryDatasource' => true
                    ]
                ],
                'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
                'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize'
            ]);
}
```

I have to use `CbEmployees` which is our user model.

Then in my custom controller, I add my login function

```
public function login()
    {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if (!$user) {
            $data = "Invalid login details";
        } else {
            $tokenId  = base64_encode(32);
            $issuedAt = time();
            $key = Security::salt();
            $data = JWT::encode(
                [
                    'alg' => 'HS256',
                    'id' => $user['id'],
                    'sub' => $user['id'],
                    'iat' => time(),
                    'exp' =>  time() + 86400,
                ],
                $key
            );
        }
        $this->ApiResponse([
            "data" => $data
        ]);
    }
```

Then I call this function using postman with body

```
{
    "username": "developer",
    "password": "dev2020"
}
```

I always get the response as **`Invalid login details`**. So the suggested solution is to check the password data type and length. The password is varchar(255). Another solution is to check the password in the entity. In the entity I have

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        if (strlen($password) > 0) {
            return Security::hash($password, 'sha1', true);
            // return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
        }
    }
```

I specifically asked why the team is using `Security::hash($password, 'sha1', true);` due to migration from cake 2 to cake 3 they have to use the same.

Why I'm getting always `Invalid login details`? What I'm doing wrong here? I can log in the using the same credentials when I'm using the application.

Comment: For starters you are using `username` when the authenticator is configured to use `user_name` (with an underscore). Also it looks like you are sending JSON data, so you must make sure that this is being decoded properly before being used by the auth component (usually this is done using the [**body parser middleware**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/middleware.html#body-parser-middleware), or the [**request handler component**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html)).

Comment: Also note that backwards compatibility can be achieved with [**fallback and weak hashers**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#changing-hashing-algorithms), or even [**custom legacy hashers**](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes), "hardcoding" the hashing in like this is not advised!

Comment: Thank you, adding fallback and weak hashers solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $this->Auth->identify();
```

This line will work when you call `AppController`. Here, define about this,
so you should move the `login` method to the other controller and extend `AppCOntroller` and then use Firebase/JWT to encode the data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).